# Neo4J query doesn't show path

Tags: neo4j

I'm creating test database for transport in a city.
My goal find path betweeb any stops.
I created this graph:

```
create (Stop_13_1:Tram {Id: 131}),
(Stop_13_2:Tram {Id: 132}),
(Stop_26_1:Tram {Id: 261}),
(Stop_26_2:Tram {Id: 262}),
(Stop_26_3_13_3:Tram {Id: 263133}),
(Stop_26_4_13_4:Tram {Id: 264134}),
(Stop_26_5_13_5:Tram {Id: 265135}),
(Stop_26_6_13_6:Tram {Id: 266136}),
(Stop_26_7_13_7:Tram {Id: 267137}),
(Stop_26_8:Tram {Id: 268}),
(Stop_7_1:Trollebus {Id: 71}),
(Stop_7_2:Trollebus {Id: 72}),
(Stop_7_3:Trollebus {Id: 73}),
(Stop_7_4:Trollebus {Id: 74}),
(Stop_7_5:Trollebus {Id: 75});
```

When I try find short way:

```
match p=shortestPath((a)-[:TO*]-(c))
where a.Id=131 and c.Id=268
return p, length(p) limit 1
```

Or this query:

```
MATCH (p1:Tram {id: 131}), (p2:Tram {id: 263133}),
      path = shortestpath((p1)-[:NEXT*]-(p2))
RETURN path
```

It's doesn't show any route.
Can you please help me edit query?

P.S. I forgot add relation:

```
MATCH (Stop_13_1 {Id: 131}),
  (Stop_13_2 {Id: 132}),
  (Stop_26_1 {Id: 261}),
  (Stop_26_2 {Id: 262}),
  (Stop_26_3_13_3 {Id: 263133}),
  (Stop_26_4_13_4 {Id: 264134}),
  (Stop_26_5_13_5 {Id: 265135}),
  (Stop_26_6_13_6 {Id: 266136}),
  (Stop_26_7_13_7 {Id: 267137}),
  (Stop_26_8 {Id: 268}),
  (Stop_7_1 {Id: 71}),
  (Stop_7_2 {Id: 72}),
  (Stop_7_3 {Id: 73}),
  (Stop_7_4 {Id: 74}),
  (Stop_7_5 {Id: 75})
  MERGE         (Stop_13_1)-    [:NEXT{distance:4.7,route:13,transport:'tram',direct:'down'}]->(Stop_13_2)
  MERGE         (Stop_13_2)-[:NEXT{distance:4.7,route:13,transport:'tram',direct:'up'}]->(Stop_13_1)
  MERGE         (Stop_13_2)-[:NEXT{distance:3.7,route:13,transport:'tram',direct:'down'}]->(Stop_26_3_13_3)
  MERGE         (Stop_26_3_13_3)-[:NEXT{distance:3.7,route:13,transport:'tram',direct:'up'}]->(Stop_13_2)
  MERGE         (Stop_26_1)-[:NEXT{distance:5.8,route:26,transport:'tram',direct:'down'}]->(Stop_26_2)
  MERGE         (Stop_26_2)-[:NEXT{distance:5.8,route:26,transport:'tram',direct:'up'}]->(Stop_26_1)
  MERGE         (Stop_26_2)-[:NEXT{distance:2.5,route:26,transport:'tram',direct:'down'}]->(Stop_26_3_13_3)
  MERGE         (Stop_26_3_13_3)-[:NEXT{distance:2.5,route:26,transport:'tram',direct:'up'}]->(Stop_26_2)
  MERGE         (Stop_26_3_13_3)-[:NEXT{distance:3.1,route:26,route:13,transport:'tram',direct:'down'}]->(Stop_26_4_13_4)
  MERGE         (Stop_26_4_13_4)-[:NEXT{distance:3.1,route:26,route:13,transport:'tram',direct:'up'}]->(Stop_26_3_13_3)
  MERGE         (Stop_26_4_13_4)-[:NEXT{distance:5.8,route:26,route:13,transport:'tram',direct:'down'}]->(Stop_26_5_13_5)
  MERGE         (Stop_26_5_13_5)-[:NEXT{distance:5.8,route:26,route:13,transport:'tram',direct:'up'}]->(Stop_26_4_13_4)
  MERGE         (Stop_26_5_13_5)-[:NEXT{distance:10.8,route:26,route:13,transport:'tram',direct:'down'}]->(Stop_26_6_13_6)
  MERGE         (Stop_26_6_13_6)-[:NEXT{distance:10.8,route:26,route:13,transport:'tram',direct:'up'}]->(Stop_26_5_13_5)
  MERGE         (Stop_26_6_13_6)-[:NEXT{distance:2.5,route:26,route:13,transport:'tram',direct:'down'}]->(Stop_26_7_13_7)
  MERGE         (Stop_26_7_13_7)-[:NEXT{distance:2.5,route:26,route:13,transport:'tram',direct:'up'}]->(Stop_26_6_13_6)
  MERGE         (Stop_26_5_13_5)-[:NEXT{distance:0.6,transport:'walking',direct:'down'}]->(Stop_7_2)
  MERGE         (Stop_7_2)-[:NEXT{distance:0.6,transport:'walking',direct:'up'}]->(Stop_26_5_13_5)
  MERGE         (Stop_26_8)-[:NEXT{distance:1,route:26,transport:'tram',direct:'down'}]->(Stop_26_7_13_7)
  MERGE         (Stop_26_7_13_7)-[:NEXT{distance:1,route:26,transport:'tram',direct:'up'}]->(Stop_26_8)
  MERGE         (Stop_7_1)-[:NEXT{distance:2.2,route:7,transport:'trolleybus',direct:'down'}]->(Stop_7_2)
  MERGE         (Stop_7_2)-[:NEXT{distance:2.2,route:7,transport:'trolleybus',direct:'up'}]->(Stop_7_1)
  MERGE         (Stop_7_2)-[:NEXT{distance:1.6,route:7,transport:'trolleybus',direct:'up'}]->(Stop_7_3)
  MERGE         (Stop_7_3)-[:NEXT{distance:2.5,route:7,transport:'trolleybus',direct:'up'}]->(Stop_7_4)
  MERGE         (Stop_7_4)-[:NEXT{distance:3.1,route:7,transport:'trolleybus',direct:'down'}]->(Stop_7_5)
  MERGE         (Stop_7_5)-[:NEXT{distance:4.4,route:7,transport:'trolleybus',direct:'down'}]->(Stop_7_2)
```

Comment: You've shown us the creation of your nodes, but I don't see the creation of any relationships. Can you add that to your description? Also, can you break up creation so you have each created element on its own line? Having to horizontally scroll through it makes it hard to read.

Comment: Christophe's answer is the right one, but for the next step I'd recommend adding the APOC Procedures plugin, which will let you use a weighted shortest path which will take into account the distance properties in your :NEXT relationships. https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures#graph-algorithms-work-in-progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to match shortest paths that have a `TO` relationship, however your graph shows that the type of the relationship is `NEXT`.

I replicated your graph here http://console.neo4j.org/r/boin78

And the following query is working as expected by just specifying the correct relationship type :

```
match p=shortestPath((a)-[:NEXT*]-(c)) 
where a.Id=131 and c.Id=268 
return p, length(p) 
limit 1
```

For the second query, you used the `id` as property while your nodes have the `Id` property name, the following is working :

```
MATCH (p1:Tram {Id: 131}), (p2:Tram {Id: 263133}), 
path = shortestpath((p1)-[:NEXT*]-(p2)) 
RETURN path
```